# Чи існує слово "нахіба"?

Tags: значення-слів, ненормативна-лексика

Кілька разів чула слово "нахіба". 
Думаю, так просто хтось пожартував під час розмови з другом, наприклад))
Наскільки я розумію, це слово означає "навіщо".
Воно дещо наближене до ненормативної лексики.

Але чи існує таке слово взагалі? Жодної інформації я не знайшла.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Скоріш за все це просто вияв чиєїсь творчості на лані ненормативної лексики. Якщо ввести в пошуковій системі слово "нахіба" більшість посилань вказують на статті, в якому це слово вжито з негативним забарвленням. Одне [джерело](http://myslovo.com/?dictionary=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%B0) також вказує синонім "навіщо". Оскільки його немає в українських словниках, на мою думку, краще утриматись від вживання цього слова.

upd. Словник сленгу і ненормативної лексики вказує значення «[нахіба](https://www.slangzone.net/word/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%B0)» як «чому? з якої причини?».

Comment: тепер пошук цього слова одним із перших результатів спрямовує на цю сторінку

Answer (score 0):

Вважаю, що це евфемізм. Застосується, коли людина бажає грубо запитати або вигукнути ненормативну фразу "На х*я?!!"

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Окрім того, цей допис не дає додаткової інформації порівняно з наявною відповіддю на це запитання.